# inputting grades (javascript function)

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make it so that the numbers I input are all on top of one another and another together in one spacing.

It supposed to show all the 3 grades I have input and when the button is clicked it should show the average and either pass or fail (I know it's supposed to be an if else statement but I really can't comprehend the codes and where will I put it)

If someone helps me solve this one can someone give me more user input / function related exercises that I can work on? thanks.

```js
var p = prompt ("enter first grade");
var c = prompt ("enter second");
var o = prompt ("enter third grade");
document.write (p);
document.write (c);
document.write (o);

function xxx (p,c,o)
{
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = ((parseInt(p)+parseInt(c)+parseInt(o)) / 3)
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>

<button onclick="xxx()">calculate</button>

<p id="demo4"></p>
<p id="demo5"></p>
```

Comment: Your solution has too many logical errors to even seem remotely on what you want to accomplish, Are you looking for a complete answer to homework? `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start first with the main non-logic problems with your code:

1. You shouldn't use `prompt`, it's just bad user experience. Dynamically create HTML elements instead.
2. You shouldn't use `document.write`. You aren't able to specify where the text should go and it makes your code vulnerable towards [XSS vulnerabilities](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).
3. You shouldn't use `onclick`. You should never mix the JS with your HTML like that. (React's HTML-like syntax is not HTML, it's JSX. It's okay to do that there.)

Now, back to the main logic which your code should follow.

1. Provide the user with one `<input type='number'>` field and an "Add" button.
2. Recalculate the result on every change, don't rely on a "Calculate" button to update your state.
3. You can use an if statement to detect a failing grade.

Here is an example of a more proper implementation of what you're trying to accomplish. I know I'm basically doing the homework task for you so I would like you to learn from this.

```js
// Storing references to elements.
const grades = document.getElementById('grades');
const template = document.getElementById('template');
const addButton = document.getElementById('add');

const averageOut = document.getElementById('average');
const failedOut = document.getElementById('failed');

function recalculate() {
  // Let's create a sum variable.
  let sum = 0;
  
  // Let's query the document for grade input fields.
  const numberFields = document.querySelectorAll('#grades input');
  
  // Iterate over number fields with for ... of.
  for (let field of numberFields) {
    // Unary + converts the value into a number.
    // parseInt can be used instead as well.
    sum += +field.value;
  }

  // .length gives you the total amount of input fields.
  // .length works on any array and some lists. (querySelectorAll returns a NodeList instead of an array)
  const average = sum/numberFields.length; 
  
  // Use innerText to prevent XSS.
  averageOut.innerText = average; 
  
  // If statement to check if the person has failed.
  if (average < 3.0) {
    failedOut.innerText = 'FAIL';
  } else {
    failedOut.innerText = 'NOT FAIL';
  }
}

// Let's recalculate the average on any change made in ANY field in the document.
// This is basically what jQuery does in its '.on(eventType, selector, listener)' method.
// This technique relies on event bubbling.
// Make sure to replace this once you start adding more functions into the document.
// Also, () => is a closure in JavaScript, which is a function but with a different context.
document.addEventListener('change', () => recalculate());

// Adding new fields.
addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Clone the template...
  const templateClone = template.cloneNode(true);

  // ...and append it to our grades.
  grades.appendChild(templateClone);

  // Also recalculate.
  recalculate();
});

// Recalculate on load.
recalculate();
```

```html
<ul id="grades">
  <li id="template">
    <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="5" />
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div>
  <span>Average:</span> <span id="average"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Failed?:</span> <span id="failed"></span>
</div>
```

What you could improve upon is adding a "Remove" button.

Comment: You also need to call `recalculate()` when a new input is added.

Comment: Added the `recalculate`.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is correct and I will study your given code. 

This is not my homework but this was a previous exercise we did in class that I actually finished and I was just trying to recreate it at home and suddenly I can't remember the code anymore. The three problems you pointed out is how my teacher is doing that particular example. I don't really know what to follow anymore since you said that it's a wrong practice. I appreciate your answer and thank you.